# Can I suppress the output when connecting to EC2 via ssh?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to copy a file to EC2 via rsync using instance connect (ssh). Unfortunately, I run into the following error message:

```
protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?
(see the rsync man page for an explanation)
rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/some-hash/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/compat.c(61) [sender=2.6.9]
```

After some [research](https://serverfault.com/a/328404), I assume it's coming from this output when connecting to the instance via ssh:

```
Last login: Sun Jan 15 13:19:10 2023 from xxx.pool.xxx.de

       __|  __|_  )
       _|  (     /   Amazon Linux 2 AMI
      ___|\___|___|

https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/
```

Does anyone know how to remove this print statement? I already checked `.bashrc` and `/etc/bashrc`, but couldn't find the echo statement anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: As it's a single file, can you try to `scp` ? This way, you can see if it's a problem of version conflict or not. BTW, the banner is made of /etc/motd.

Comment: Run `touch ~/.hushlogin`.  That said, this is not your problem, the motd is not shown for the non-interactive connection rsync uses, otherwise it would be nearly useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should not be the problem. It is more likely that there is a mismatch between the rsync versions used in the source and target.

Comment: Yes, apparently the default rsync version on Mac is from 2006 because they don't include anything released under GPLv3 or similar licenses. After updating it using `brew install rsync` and signing out and back in again, it worked! Thanks!